# creating a photo album (lightbox, etc) with facebook photos

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress, integration

I'm trying to have a photo gallery display in a Lightbox (or a similar gallery type thing), but my client wants the photos to come from a Facebook album to avoid having to upload photos twice.

i'm working within wordpress, but i looked around at some of the plugins available and they don't seem very promising.

what is my best plan of attack here? I have't really begun to dig into the facebook api, but if that's what you guys suggest than i'll go ahead and do it.i'm pretty familiar with javascript and php. i don't want to go down that rabbit hole until i'm sure that it's going to work.

i'm just really looking for people to share some insights, because i don't really know where to begin.

Edit:

This is where i'm stuck...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Facebook Photo Gallery</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/356611067762340/photos').then(function(response) {
        // 0-8, 0 returns the largest available images, 8 the smallest
        var imageIndex = 5;

        var images = _(response.data)
            .chain()
            .pluck('images')
            .pluck(imageIndex)
            .value();

        console.log(images);

        _(images).each(function(image) {
            $('#image-container').append(
                $('<img>').attr('src', image.source)
            );
        });

        });
    </script>


    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="image-container"></div>​

    </body>
    </html>
```

this seems totally valid to me, why isn't it working...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the album is public and owned by a Facebook page (not a profile), this should be easy. I did this with a wedding website.

Here's the album I used: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.428653951748.228645.6815841748&type=3

And here's the Facebook API endpoint I needed: http://graph.facebook.com/428653951748/photos

You just need to the album ID which you should be able to extract from the Facebook album's URL, then fire off a request to graph.facebook.com/[id]/photos. You get back a nice array of images and URLs for different sizes of the image.

Example, using jQuery and Underscore.js (also at http://jsfiddle.net/ey2Pd/2/):

```
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/10150198713667381/photos').then(function(response) {

    // 0-8, 0 returns the largest available images, 8 the smallest
    var imageIndex = 4;

    var images = _(response.data).chain()
        .pluck('images')
        .pluck(imageIndex)
    .value();

    _(images).each(function(image) {
        $('#image-container').append(
            $('<img>').attr('src', image.source)
        );
    });

});​
```

Comment: what does the request to facebook look like?

Comment: Just a simple GET request. Open that URL in your browser and you can see the JSON response.

Comment: i'm able to see the pictures, but i'm getting every size of every picture. how would I loop through and only grab the 960x540 from each? i'm getting confused with all these nested arrays...

Comment: figurued it out. forgot to include underscore.js... duh